# References for tiny sample statistics

Tags: references, small-sample

There are multiple fascinating problems and approaches connected to [really small samples](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/83199/35989). It is possible to estimate confidence intervals using a [single point](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1807/how-to-perform-students-t-test-having-only-sample-size-sample-average-and-popu/1836#1836), or there are well known problems such as [German tank problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) (or similar [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14964/estimate-population-size-based-on-repeated-observation)) etc. I recently asked about forecasting with [short time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135061/best-method-for-short-time-series). The problem is also that most of the statistical methods are designed for large samples and many theorems are described in context of "$n \rightarrow \infty$" what makes it troublesome to generalize them to really small samples. Because in general it is hard to find literature dealing with the topic of tiny samples I wanted to ask if you could suggest any?

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in how to deal with small samples in **sampling** (and in particular, for survey sampling), I'd suggest you read [Rao, *Small Area Estimation* (2003, Wiley)](https://books.google.com/books?hl=fr&lr=&id=f8NY6M-5EEwC&oi=fnd&pg=PR7&dq=small%20area%20estimation&ots=u0OUfLj9-R&sig=H0dRPzBqFnu8dPzX-frQ7Za0MZg).

I also recently heard M. Hidiroglou give a general lecture about the topic ([long abstract here](http://paperssondages14.sfds.asso.fr/submission_113.pdf)). I'm definitely not a small sample/small area specialist, and I thought his talk was a good introduction to the subject.